# line chart or column chart

Tags: thesis, graphics

I want to show the average response time based on number of tasks on a device on a chart. So the x-axis is "number of tasks" and y-axis is "average response time".

My question is which charts I can use? a line chart or a column chart?

Answer (score 4):

Well, this should give you an idea:

[image]

Source is https://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/53/file-863940581-pdf/Data_Visualization_101_How_to_Design_Charts_and_Graphs.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Probably an x-y scatter chart with some regression relation (line or curve).  You have a functional relationship versus a time series or categories.  Also likely many points.  All of these argue for x-y versus columns (although not dispositive).

In addition to Mike's excellent suggestion, please skim this book, especially first couple chapters:  [https://www.amazon.com/Say-Charts-Executives-Visual-Communication/dp/007136997X](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/007136997X)

[The book is not perfect.  You will need to become an educated user of charts and look at different ideas.  But it is very strong on "use this chart for this sort of message" and for conveying things strongly and simply.]